# Wordpress Multiple stylesheets

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to have multiple styles on my website. To me, this code should work but if anyone could tell me why it is not that would be great!

```
if (is_front_page()) {
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-frontpage', get_template_directory_uri().'/stylee.css');
} else{
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-frontpage', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/temp.css');
}
```

This is located in my `functions.php`.

Comment: This is located in my functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_front_page()` will always return false when is used in `functions.php` like that. You have to create a hook using `wp` to get it working. The reason why is not working is because when functions.php boots Wordpress doesn't know about the content of the query, so it won't know the type of the page you are one. Try this:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'check_is_front_page' );
function check_is_front_page() {
   if(is_front_page()){
      wp_enqueue_style('custom-frontpage', get_template_directory_uri().'/stylee.css');
  }else{
      wp_enqueue_style('custom-frontpage', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/temp.css');
  }
}
```

You can read about this specific hook **[here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp)**.

You can read more about hooks and how they work **[here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)**.